# XPath Find any element with text() within node selection

Tags: xpath

I have a fairly deeply nested xml structure and I would like to find an element with a particular value after I have already selected a node. In the sample below I have an array of 'B' and after selecting each of the 'B' nodes I would like to get the text of one of the children (which are not consistent) that starts with the word 'history'

```
<A>
    <Items>
        <B>
            <C>
                <D>history: pressed K,E</D>  // could be nested anywhere
            </C>
        </B>
        <B>
            <C>
                <E>history: pressed W</E>
            </C>
        </B>
    </Items>
</A>


    // Select the nodes from the array (B)
var nodes = select(xmldoc, "//A/Items/B");

    // Iterate through the nodes.
nodes.forEach(node){

    // is it possible to select any element that starts with the text 'history' from the already selected node.
var history = select(node, "???[starts-with(.,'history')]");
```

all the samples I have seen start with : //*[text()] which searches from the root of the structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
//B//*[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'history')]
```

looks like it would do what you intend.

It selects *"any descendant element of `<B>` whose text content starts with `'history'`"*.

Manual iteration to find further nodes is not typically necessary. XPath does that for you. If you must iterate for some other reason, use the context node `.` to select.

```
nodes.forEach(function (node) {
    var history = select(node, "./*[starts-with(.,'history')]");
});
```

---

If you are actually looking for *"any text node..."*

```
//B//text()[starts-with(normalize-space(), 'history')]
```

Or *"any element node that has no further child elements..."*

```
//B//*[not(*) and starts-with(normalize-space(), 'history')]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still returns 2 results and not the result of the selected node. It would be because we are starting at //B which has multiple records.

Comment: Something like this works:
select(node, "C/*/[starts-with(normalize-space(.),'history')]");

so it will select from element <D> or <E>. 
The * searches all the children at the current level it doesn't search the children's children which makes sense. 
I was actually looking for a way to do a full search and all children from the current node.